# Disponibilizar arquivos de acordo com o grupo de clientes usando php

Tags: php, html, mysqli, opencart

Estou precisando disponibilizar em uma página de informação do Opencart 2 arquivos de tabelas de preços, onde uma é para varejo e a outra para atacado. A página que mostrará o link só é acessada se o cliente fizer o login, agora eu gostaria que se ele for cadastrado como varejo tenha acesso apenas ao link da tabela V, mas se ele for cadastrado como atacado ele apenas veja o link para a tabela A. A tabela de cadastro de clientes se chama custumer e a coluna que indica o id do grupo é group_id, o id para Varejo é 1 e para Atacado é 2. Gostaria que os especialistas me ajudassem pois estou começando com o PHP agora e está muito difícil fazer isso. Obrigado.

Como a pagina onde quero inserir o código já está dentro de uma sessão eu ia pular esta verificação, então pensei assim:

```
    <?php 
    // Verificar se o grupo é menor que 2
    $consulta_grupo = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE group_id < 2";

    if ( empty($consulta_grupo)) {
    $linkvarejo  = "<a href="http://localhost/tabelavarejo.pdf">Tabela Varejo</a>";
    } else {
    $linkatacado = "<a href="http://localhost/tabelaatacado.pdf">Tabela Atacado</a>"; }
    ?>
```

Comment: é só fazer um if. mostre o que já tentou fazer

Comment: Como a pagina onde quero inserir o código já está dentro de uma sessão eu ia pular esta verificação, então pensei assim:

<?php 
$consulta_grupo = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customer_group_id < 2";

Comment: Pensou certo mas não vejo sentido no sinal de menor `<`, seria bem mais simples apenas `= 1` ou `= 2`. Era só essa sua dúvida?

Comment: meu comentário completo

Como a pagina onde quero inserir o código já está dentro de uma sessão eu ia pular esta verificação, então pensei assim:

<?php 
// Verificar se o grupo é menor que 2
$consulta_grupo = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE group_id < 2";

// Pórem não sei como usar o 
if ( empty($consulta_grupo)) {
$linkatacado = "tabelaatacado.pdf";
} else {
$linkvarejo = "tabelavarejo.pdf":
?>

Comment: pensei em usar o < 2 para indicar que o grupo_id é de varejo e que deveria mostrar o link de varejo e se fosse maior o de atacado

Comment: coloque o código na pergunta do que já tentou fazer. Mostre as consultas ao banco de dados que puxam o valor do grupo do usuário

Comment: Já adicionei na pergunta o que eu tentei fazer

Answer (score 0):

Pesquisas em Sql para retornar dados mais rápidos devem ser o mais objetivas possíveis.
É melhor usar = 1 do que < 2. Nesse caso supondo que por acaso chegue 0, -1 ou qualquer outro valor, sempre será exibido a tabela de varejo e isso pode não ser o seu desejo.
O melhor é quando o usuario logar você guardar o grupo dele na [sessao](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.session.php) do PHP. Deste modo seria possível fazer algo assim:

```
$usuario_grupo = $_SESSION['grupoUsuario'];

if (  $usuario_grupo == 1) {
    $linkvarejo  = "<a href="http://localhost/tabelavarejo.pdf">Tabela Varejo</a>";
    } else {
    $linkatacado = "<a href="http://localhost/tabelaatacado.pdf">Tabela Atacado</a>"; }
```

Supondo que você não queira guardar na sessão o grupo mas guarde o ID, nesse caso você teria que fazer a sql para descobrir o grupo que o cliente pertence:

```
 $usuario_id = $_SESSION['usuarioId'];

 $consulta_grupo_do_usuario = "SELECT grupo_id FROM customer WHERE id == $usuarioId";

if ( $consulta_grupo_do_usuario['grupo_id'] == 1 ) {
$linkvarejo  = "<a href="http://localhost/tabelavarejo.pdf">Tabela Varejo</a>";
} else {
$linkatacado = "<a href="http://localhost/tabelaatacado.pdf">Tabela Atacado</a>"; }
```

Comment: Israel acho que é bem isso que você postou, porem me deparei com outro problema o opencart ele não permite que eu coloque linhas de comando em php. Não sei agora oq fazer.

Comment: qual erro ele apresenta?

Comment: Não apresenta erro nenhum ao salvar o artigo com o código PHP ele simplesmente o código é suprimido pois não sei se é o sistema do opencart que muda a tag de abertura do php em comentário, exemplo:
    
Código original:
   <? php
   $usuario_i... ?>

Ele muda para:
    <!--?php 
    ....>